# How to apply regex to an element in a series using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and column named as 'Values'.

Please find the code below to create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
 'Values':[np.nan,np.nan,'1.Yes','2.No', np.nan],
       'Ethnicity':['1.Chinese','2.Indian','3.Malay',np.nan,np.nan]})
```

The dataframe looks like as shown below after executing the above piece of code

[image]

I have given only a sample data and this is a part of the main program.

From the above dataframe, I would like to find whether a 'Values' column of a specific row contains 'Yes' or 'No' as values using regex

For example, I would like to know whether df['Values][2] contains 'Yes' keyword/term in its value

To that, I wrote the below piece of code but am not able to get the expected output

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'].astype(str) 
df['Values'][2].contains('Yes|No',regex=True)
```

Inspite of multiple tries/variations of above code and search through SO, I am not able to get/resolve this. I am getting the below error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

How can I get whether the value 'Yes' or 'No' is present in specific cell of a column in dataframe.

Please note that this is part of a larger program where I use for loop and indices. Hence, I would like to perform the check at cell level and get the output. Using **df.isin** will not be of any help

Comment: `import re` and then `bool(re.search('Yes|No' , df['Values'][2]))`?

Comment: alternatively: `df['Values'].str.contains('Yes|No',regex=True)[2]`

Comment: You're forgetting to use the `.str` acccessor, eg: `df['Values'].str.contains(...)`...

Comment: Looks like you might even just want to create a new Series of booleans using `df['Values'].str.contains('Yes|No', na=False)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand but when type(df['Values'][2] = Str, do I have to still use str?

Comment: no... because you're then dealing directly with a `str` object which doesn't have a `contains` and its native membership testing doesn't have regex capabilities, you'll have to use `re.match` as @Wiktor said in the first comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.contains('Yes|No',regex=True)`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Person_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
 'Values':[np.nan,np.nan,'1.Yes','2.No', np.nan],
       'Ethnicity':['1.Chinese','2.Indian','3.Malay',np.nan,np.nan]})

print(df["Values"].str.contains('Yes|No',regex=True))
```

**Output:**

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    True
3    True
4     NaN
Name: Values, dtype: object
```